# Dynamic chart using Fiji (Exadel) library & jsf

Tags: apache-flex, jsp, jsf, charts

My requirement is to display tables from database in Graph format and I am using fiji for the same. And on doing so I am encountering and exception, 
My jsp page is as follows.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:fiji="http://exadel.com/fiji">
    <fiji:columnChart id="columnChartOne" value="#{GraphBean.monthMap}" title="One-series Column Chart" barCaption="none"
                      barColors="#{GraphBean.colors}" captionX="Months" captionY="Amount" toolTipValue="{y} {name} are sold in {x}"
                      subtitle="Hardware sales per month" width="400" height="400">
        <fiji:chartData type="name" value="#{GraphBean.names}" />
    </fiji:columnChart>
</ui:composition>
```

My bean is as follows :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;


public class GraphBean {

    private Integer data;
    private  Map<String, Integer> monthMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
    private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>();
    Random rnd = new Random(new Date().getTime());

    public GraphBean() {
        super();
        generateData();
    }

    private void generateData() {
        monthMap.put("January", getData());
        monthMap.put("February", getData());
        monthMap.put("March", getData());
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getMonthMap() {
        return monthMap;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getNames(){
        names.add("Motherboards");
        return names;
    } 

    public ArrayList<String> getColors(){
        colors.add("#5db2c2");
        return colors;
    } 

    public Integer getData() {
        data = rnd.nextInt(50);
        return data;
    }
}
```

I have made entry for the bean in the faces-config.xml.

Comment: what is your excpetion?
as well, you are probably writing a facelet page (xhtml) and no jsp if you use ui:composition.

Comment: No I am using jsp .........so how to do that in a jsp?

Comment: can you please write your exception?
as well, how do you use jsp if I see ui:composition which represents facelet?

Comment: **Exception :** 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP

Can you please clarify the second part of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSF, you could render the page either with facelet or with JSP (although not recommended)
As far as I see, you are trying to load JSP page, while adding a facelet tag:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:fiji="http://exadel.com/fiji">
...
</ui:composition>
```

. If you would like to use the pages with facelet, you can download an example that is using facelet [here](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/code/jsf-blank.zip) . As you can see, the name of the pages are postfixed with .xhtml and not with .jsp.

If you would like to use JSP your page has to be:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://exadel.com/fiji" prefix="fiji" %>

    <html>
     <head>
      <title>enter your name page</title>
     </head>
     <body>
<f:view>
            <fiji:columnChart id="columnChartOne" value="#{GraphBean.monthMap}" title="One-series Column Chart" barCaption="none"
                              barColors="#{GraphBean.colors}" captionX="Months" captionY="Amount" toolTipValue="{y} {name} are sold in {x}"
                              subtitle="Hardware sales per month" width="400" height="400">
                <fiji:chartData type="name" value="#{GraphBean.names}" />
            </fiji:columnChart>
       </f:view> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Again, I would recommend to you to use facelet, if it's a new project.

See a tutorial [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-facelets/)

Comment: Pssh, your JSP example is invalid. There's still an `</ui:composition>` there and you'd like to wrap the JSF components in a `<f:view>`. Points for nailing down the problem though: you cannot mix legacy JSP with its sucessor Facelets.

Comment: @BalusC - I edited my answer. I just copied his code too quickly

Comment: Thanks a loot Odelya & BalusC it seems you all know everyting. I am just an ignorant kid.............thanks again for your valuable time.

Comment: hey can you specify which all jars are needed for fiji charts?

Comment: @ Odelya ....thanks again 

I am encountering this exeception do you have a solution 

**The absolute uri: http://exadel.com/fiji cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
**

Comment: do you have the jar in your application?

Comment: flamingo-service-jsf-1.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
 amf-serializer-1.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
 common-annotations.jar
 commons-beanutils.jar
 commons-collections.jar
 commons-digester.jar
 commons-logging.jar
 el-api-1.0.jar
 el-impl-1.0.jar
 fiji-api-1.0.0.jar
 fiji-ui-1.0.0.jar
 jsf-api-1.2_09.jar
 jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar
 jsf-impl-1.2_09.jar
 jstl-1.2.jar
 laguna.jar
 richfaces-api-3.2.2.CR3.jar
 richfaces-impl-3.2.2.CR3.jar
 richfaces-ui-3.2.2.CR3.jar
 standard.jar

Comment: Can you post a new question for that?